# using spotipy library in python authentication error

Tags: python, spotipy

Hello guys i am trying to create a function in which would use the spotify api and the spotipy library for python

i am having issues with  the redirect_uri for this even if i have set both here and on my spotify dashboard the same uri

i am getting an error for

OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

def create_playlist():

```
client_id = '_______'
client_secret = '______'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'
username = 'csrupido01'
scope = 'playlist-modify-public'



token = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, username=username , client_id= client_id,client_secret =client_secret ,redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager = token)

playlist = input ("Enter the name of the playlist: ")
desc = input ("Enter a description for the playlist: ")

spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(user=username,name=playlist,public=True,description=desc)

song= input("Enter a song:")
songlist = []

while song != "quit":
    search = spotifyObject.search(q=song)
    
    songlist.append(result['track']['item'][0][uri])
    song = input ("Enter another song: ")
    
pplay =spotifyObject.user_playlist(user=username)
lists = pplay ['items'][0]['id']

spotifyObject.user_playlist_add_track (user=username,playlist_id=lists,tracks=songlist)
```

create_playlist()

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the port you are trying to use is already in use. Try changing the port in your code and [dashboard](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/) to another number and check if it works.